# MySQL and PHP delete row from dropdown

Tags: php, mysql, select, drop-down-menu

I wish to use dropdown to list all rows from database. When I select one option, delete that selected row with button. 
Here what I have by now, this only shows dropdown:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
die('Nije se moguće konektovati: ' . mysql_error());
}

 mysql_select_db("videoteka", $con);

$result = mysql_query("select ime,id from filmovi");

$options=""; 

echo "Odaberite film:";

 while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

$id=$row["id"]; 
$ime=$row["ime"]; 
$options.="<OPTION VALUE=\"$id\">".$ime.'</option>';
}

mysql_close($con);
```

And in body:

```
<select name=thing> 
<option value=0><?=$options?></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Sorry, but we can't (shouldn't) do your homework for you. Did you try something for the delete part already? Can you use JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: I can only use PHP. I can't relly figure out how to use <option> with button.

Comment: that's the point of homework. StackOverflow is nice for learning but for this you should start reading it... :-)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so two things, just to try and put you in the right direction: first, in the body you can remove the `<option>` tag, since your php variable already contains those.

```
<select name=thing> 
<?=$options?>
</select>
```

Second, the delete part. There are different ways to do this, but one thing you will certainly need is an HTML form. Your select (and the button) will need to be in this form, which will be submitted to this very same PHP page. In the beginning of your PHP code you will check the `$_POST` variable to determine what row to delete. I hope you know what `$_POST` is, otherwise this is going to be a pretty useless explanation.

Comment: Ok. Now I made form with action delete.php and in it I have: $delete = mysql_query("DELETE * FROM filmovi WHERE $_POST[thing]"). But I don't think this is right.

Comment: Well, it also depends on the result you want. Is delete.php a different page from the one with the form? Anyway, in the post variable you will find the selected id (as $_POST['thing'], yes), so the query will be something like $delete = mysql_query("DELETE FROM filmovi WHERE id = '".$_POST['thing']."';");
I know this is not very detailed, but I hope you understand that this is not the right place for a basic PHP lesson.

Comment: Wow. It worked just the way I wanted. Thanks very much! Sorry for amateurism.